# Windows Phone 8 webbrowser control behaviour

Tags: windows-phone-8

How can I prevent zooming and panning of web pages in a `WebBrowser` control in Windows Phone 8? I put the below meta tag in my web page, but it had no effect.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no;">
```

Also, while vertical scrolling up and down, white space is show in my `WebBrowser` control. Does anyone know how to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
         -ms-touch-action: none;
     }
```